# Difficulty with Plotting the Soliton Solution of a Nonlinear Schrödinger Equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics, graphics3d

Given the non-linear equation Schroediger [NLS]

[image].
We know one of the most important solutions is the soliton solution

[image]
I am trying to study the solution at

```
v=1;
k=1;
\[Sigma] = 1;
\[CapitalOmega] = 2;
```

Then I defined the solution $u$

```
u[x_, t_] = 
 Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[Abs[(\[CapitalOmega] - k^2*v)/\[Sigma]]]*
  Sech[Sqrt[Abs[(\[CapitalOmega] - k^2*v)/v]]*(x - 2*k*v*t)]*
  Exp[I(k*x - \[CapitalOmega]*t)]
```

The i tried to create snapshots at $t=0,2.4, 3.5 sec$ when $x \in [-50,50]$

```
fig1 = Plot[u[x, 0], {x, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and then to create a 3D graph of $|u|$

```
Plot3D[u[x, t], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, x, U}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[{"DeepSeaColors", "Reverse"}][#3] &), 
 PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 3, Mesh -> None, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"]]
```

But it does not return anything. What could I change?

Comment: Need to use `I` for the imaginary I.

Comment: @BillWatts I have changed it but still no results

Comment: Also, complex numbers don't plot.  Take the real or imaginary part before plotting.

Comment: @BillWatts could you show me please?

Comment: If you want, instead of `Re` and `Im`, you can plot the `Abs[u[x,t]]` for all plots.

Comment: @BillWatts If i compare ```Abs[u[x,t]]``` and ```Re[u[x,t]]``` i can see the difference

Comment: Yes, there is a difference.  In your post, you say you want a plot of Abs[u].  The absolute value of the complex number `a+b I` is `Sqrt[a^2+b^2]`, where the Real part is `a` and the imaginary part is `b`.  It depends on the value you want.

Comment: @BillWatts ok thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
u[x_, t_] = ComplexExpand[Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[Abs[(\[CapitalOmega] - k^2*v)/\[Sigma]]]*
Sech[Sqrt[Abs[(\[CapitalOmega] - k^2*v)/v]]*(x - 2*k*v*t)]*Exp[I*(k*x - \[CapitalOmega]*t)]]

Plot[Evaluate[Im[u[x, 0]]], {x, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot[Evaluate[Re[u[x, 0]]], {x, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: and i can do the shame to plot 3D?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) and [`ReImPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReImPlot.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

v = 1;
k = 1;
σ = 1;
Ω = 2;

u[x_, t_] = 
 ComplexExpand[
   Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[Abs[(Ω - k^2*v)/σ]]*
    Sech[Sqrt[Abs[(Ω - k^2*v)/v]]*(x - 2*k*v*t)]*
    Exp[I*(k*x - Ω*t)]] // Simplify

(* Sqrt[2] Sech[2 t - x] (Cos[2 t - x] - I Sin[2 t - x]) *)

Manipulate[
 ReImPlot[u[x, t], {x, -50, 50},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1.5},
  ReImStyle -> {Lighter[Blue, 0.6], Red},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.3, .6}],
  MaxRecursion -> 5],
 {{t, 0}, 0, 3.5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}]
```

[image]